# $n^{th}$ derivative of $\frac 1 {(1-x)}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I was trying to calculate the $n^{th}$ derivative of the function
$$f(x) = \dfrac{1}{1-x}$$

And I already found a couple of derivatives but I'm not able to find the pattern.

$f_1(x) = \dfrac{1}{(1-x)^{2}}$

$f_2(x) = \dfrac{2}{(1-x)^{3}}$

$f_3(x) = \dfrac{6}{(1-x)^{5}}$

$f_4(x) = \dfrac{30}{(1-x)^{9}}$

$f_5(x) = \dfrac{270}{(1-x)^{17}}$

Can someone please help me find the pattern in this derivative?

Comment: Starting with the third derivative your results are wrong.

Comment: Please check the power of $1-x$ in $f_3(x)$. It is wrong. Write $f_i(x) = a_i \times (1-x)^{n_i}$, and find recursion relations for $a_i$ and $n_i$ by differentiating.

Comment: Oh sorry didn't see my mistake, thanks for the help.

Comment: The general form should be $f^{(n)}(x) = \frac{n!}{(1-x)^{n+1}}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative of $x^{n}$ is $nx^{n-1}$, whatever integer is $n$. Thus the derivative of $(1-x)^n$ is $-n(1-x)^{n-1}$ and the sequence you get is therefore
$$
\frac{1}{1-x}\quad
\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\quad
\frac{2}{(1-x)^3}\quad
\frac{6}{(1-x)^4}\quad
\cdots
$$
and a simple induction will confirm it: the $n$-th derivative is
$$
f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{n!}{(1-x)^{n+1}}
$$
Indeed, the derivative of the function $n!(1-x)^{-n-1}$ is
$$
n!(-n-1)(-1)(1-x)^{-n-2}=\frac{(n+1)!}{(1-x)^{n+2}}
$$